# How to show fragment dialog in button.setOnClickListener from Adapter class in Kotlin-MVP?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, kotlin, android-mvp

I'm developing one Android application using this [Kotlin-MVP](https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/android-kotlin-mvp-architecture) structure. I have one activity and it contains TabLayout of 4 fragments. All fragment has one button in RecyclerView. I need to show one "Fragment Dialog" on that button click listener. Can you please let me know how can I show fragment dialog on button click listener from adapter class? Please review screenshot.

[image]

I'm accessing button on click listener event from Adapter class which is below `itemView.btn_accept.setOnClickListener`:

```
class InApprovalAdapter(private val jobListItems: MutableList<JobItem>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<InApprovalAdapter.JobViewHolder>() {

private var _ProfileId: Long? = null;

fun getProfileId(): Long? {
    return _ProfileId
}

fun setProfileId(s: Long) {
    _ProfileId = s
}

private var _UserToken : String? = null;

fun getUserToken(): String? {
    return _UserToken
}

fun setUserToken(s: String) {
    _UserToken = s
}

private var _UserTypeId : Long? = null;
fun getUserTypeId(): Long? {
    return _UserTypeId
}

fun setUserTypeId(s: Long) {
    _UserTypeId = s
}


override fun getItemCount() = this.jobListItems.size

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: JobViewHolder, position: Int) = holder.let {
    it.clear()
    it.onBind(position)
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int) = JobViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context)
        .inflate(R.layout.item_inapproval_list, parent, false))

internal fun addJobsToList(jobs: List<JobItem>, profileId: Long?, userToken: String?, userTypeId: Long?) {
    this.jobListItems.addAll(jobs)
    setProfileId(profileId!!.toLong())
    setUserToken(userToken!!)
    setUserTypeId(userTypeId!!)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

inner class JobViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

    fun clear() {
        itemView.tv_job_id.text = "";
        itemView.tv_job_title.text= "";
        //itemView.tv_job_description.text ="";
        itemView.tv_job_category.text ="";
        itemView.tv_date_created.text ="";
    }

    fun onBind(position: Int) {

        val (jobId, name, description, serviceId, serviceName,
                address, engineerIds, engineerNames, startDateTimeUtc,
                startDateTimeLocal, endDateTimeUtc, endDateTimeLocal,
                customerId, customerName, customerMobile, customerAltMobile,
                priorityTypeId, priorityTypeName, statusTypeId, statusTypeName,
                isDeleted, isStatusTypeActive, createdBy, createdByName,
                dateCreatedPretty, modifiedBy, modifiedByName ,hasJobMedia,
                jobMedias, hasJobFeedback, jobDetailsImage, dateCreatedUtc, dateModifiedUtc) = jobListItems[position]

        inflateData(jobId, name,
                description,
                serviceId,
                serviceName,
                address,
                engineerIds,
                engineerNames,
                startDateTimeUtc,
                startDateTimeLocal,
                endDateTimeUtc,
                endDateTimeLocal,
                customerId,
                customerName,
                customerMobile,
                customerAltMobile,
                priorityTypeId,priorityTypeName,
                statusTypeId,
                statusTypeName,
                isDeleted,
                isStatusTypeActive,
                createdBy,
                createdByName,
                dateCreatedPretty,
                modifiedBy,
                modifiedByName ,
                hasJobMedia,
                jobMedias, hasJobFeedback, jobDetailsImage, dateCreatedUtc, dateModifiedUtc)
        setItemClickListener(jobId)
    }

    private fun setItemClickListener(jobId: Long?) {
        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            jobId?.let {
                try {
                    val intent = Intent(itemView.context, ServiceDetailActivity::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra("JobId", jobId)
                    itemView.context.startActivity(intent)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Toast.makeText(itemView.context, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
        }

        itemView.btn_accept.setOnClickListener {



        }

        itemView.btn_reject.setOnClickListener{

        }
    }
    private fun inflateData(jobId: Long?, name: String?, description: String?, serviceId: Long?, serviceName: String?, address: String?, engineerIds: String?,
                            engineerNames: String?, startDateTimeUtc: String?, startDateTimeLocal: String?, endDateTimeUtc: String?,
                            endDateTimeLocal: String?, customerId: Long?, customerName: String?, customerMobile:String?, customerAltMobile: String?,
                            priorityTypeId: Long?, priorityTypeName: String?, statusTypeId: Long?, statusTypeName: String?, isDeleted: Boolean?, isStatusTypeActive: Boolean?,
                            createdBy: Long?, createdByName: String?, dateCreatedPretty: String?, modifiedBy: Long?, modifiedByName: String?, hasJobMedia: Boolean?,
                            jobMedias: List<JobDetailsImage>?, hasJobFeedback: Boolean?, jobDetailsImage:  List<JobDetailsImage>?, dateCreatedUtc: String?, dateModifiedUtc: String?) {
        name.let {
            itemView.tv_job_title.text = it;
        }
        jobId.let {
            itemView.tv_job_id.text = "Job\n#" + it
        }
        /*description.let {
            itemView.tv_job_description.text = it
        }*/
        serviceName.let {
            itemView.tv_job_category.text = it
        }
        dateCreatedPretty.let {
            itemView.tv_date_created.text = it
        }

        if(getUserTypeId() == AppConstants.UserType.Administrator.type ||
                getUserTypeId() == AppConstants.UserType.Admin.type)
        {
            itemView.btn_reject.text = "Reject";
        }
        else
        {
            itemView.btn_reject.text = "Delete";
            itemView.btn_accept.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }

    private fun callJobStatusChangeApi(jobId: Long?, statusTypeId: Long?)
    {
        val androidId = Settings.Secure.getString(itemView.context.contentResolver, Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID)

        Rx2AndroidNetworking.post(ApiEndPoint.ENDPOINT_JOB_CHANGEJOBSTATUS)
                .addHeaders("Authorization", "bearer " + getUserToken())
                .addQueryParameter("profileId",  getProfileId().toString())
                .addQueryParameter("jobId", jobId.toString())
                .addQueryParameter("statusTypeId", statusTypeId.toString())
                .addQueryParameter("DeviceId", androidId.toString())
                .build()
                .getAsObject(BaseResponse::class.java, object : ParsedRequestListener<BaseResponse> {

                    override fun onResponse(baseResponse: BaseResponse) {
                        // do anything with response
                        println("succeeded : " + baseResponse.succeeded)
                        println("message : " + baseResponse.message)

                        if(baseResponse.succeeded)
                        {
                            val inApprovalFragment : InApprovalFragment = InApprovalFragment()
                            inApprovalFragment.showStatusSubmissionSuccessMessage(itemView.context, baseResponse.message);
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }

                    override fun onError(anError: ANError) {
                        // handle error
                        println(anError.message);
                    }

                })
    }

}

}
```

Comment: It's not clear where is the problem. If you have problems accessing the FragmentManager then you could access it from the Context(which will be the Activity) of any view like you already do with itemView. Another approach would be to pass a lambda to your adapter which you'll invoke in the accept button's OnClickListener. As the adapter and this lambda will be created in the Fragment class you can access the FragmentManager with getFragmentManager().

Comment: @Luksprog This is the problem. I cannot access getFragmentManager()    in adapter class. I'm new in Android and started learning Kotlin with MVP structure. Do you have an example of lambda?

Comment: @Luksprog I tried this code `ServiceAssignDialog.newInstance().let {
                        it?.show(supportFragmentManager);
                    }` but it says unresolved reference `supportFragmentManager`.

Comment: I've shown you an example. The code you posted in the comment will not work because you're out of scope with the FragmentManager in the adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have problems accessing the FragmentManager you can simply pass a lambda to your adapter as the accept button's OnClickListener:

```
class InApprovalAdapter(
    private val jobListItems: MutableList<JobItem>
    // If you have data to pass to the handler(like a jobId for example) 
    // modify the lambda like (Int) -> Unit
    private val acceptHandler: () -> Unit
    ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<InApprovalAdapter.JobViewHolder>() {
```

Then you can use that lambda:

```
itemView.btn_accept.setOnClickListener {
     acceptHandler()
}
```

Then create the adapter:

```
val adapter = InApprovalAdapter(theListOfItems, val clickListener: (Item) -> Unit) {
    // I'm assuming you're creating this adapter inside the Fragment class
    // so at this point you can access getFragmentManager()
    // ideally you'll let the presenter know that something happened in the view: presenter.userAcceptedJob()
    // and the presenter will call back a method on the view to actually show the DialogFragment.
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution but it doesn't work. I have created `partItemClicked` lambda but it couldn't work. I applied your logic in `PendingFragment.kt` and `PendingAdapter.kt` on `itemView.tv_select_engineer.setOnClickListener`. Please review my code here, https://gist.github.com/kg-dexterity/d76d285eb6e7a195c9a427bc1f6880ba

Comment: @Keval Your code is a bit confusing. First of all you set a OnClickListener on the itemView.tv_select_engineer twice: one in the inflateData() method correctly(invoking clickListener()) and then again in the setItemClickListener() method incorrectly(that will not work because you don't have a reference to the FragmentManager). Also, the adapter reference in the PendingFragment, gets injected(which you probably shouldn't do) and then in displayJobList() it gets replaced with another PendingAdapter instance.

Comment: @Keval I revamped the code you posted with a more simple solution to follow that will let you keep the dependency injection part: https://gist.github.com/luksprog/802cab392cd357862fae57455a9d7a22

Comment: Your both solutions working fine. I really appreciate. Thanks @Lusprog

Answer (score 0):

I does same thing , shown custom dialog from adapter which is called from fragment.Not need to make dialog fragment,it will do same thing.

Pass activity from fragment while setting adapter

in ListFragment:-

```
rvAdapter = Listadapter( listnotes,activity!!)
```

in Listadapter class :-

```
class Listadapter( val DataList: ArrayList<String>?,val parentActivity: Activity) : RecyclerView.Adapter<Listadapter.ViewHolder>() {}
```

in onBindViewHolder method:-

```
view.notes.setOnClickListener {
        DialogNOTES(parentActivity,DataList[position])
    }
```

make method to show custom dailog in Listadapter class:-

```
private fun DialogNOTES(parentActivity: Activity,notes:String) {
    val dialog = Dialog(parentActivity)
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
    dialog.setCancelable(true)
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.notes_dilog)//custom dialog layout 
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

    dialog.show()

    dialog.dilog_notes.setText(notes)


}
```